# Any alternatives to rendering the source of a webpage without the need of a webbrowser in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is there any libraries specifically targeted towards rendering web pages or am I stuck using Selenium And PhantomJs To render the web page and then spit back the source code because that method I've been doing is pretty resource heavy especially since all I really need is the source code of the rendered web page.

Comment: Side note: search for libraries is off-topic on SO, but your question is confusing even if it would not look like resource request... So consider to [edit]… More specifically "targeted towards rendering web pages" means you are looking for some equivalent of a browser but you are not happy with two most common methods of rendering pages... What exactly you are looking to achieve? (Maybe you should glance through "web scraping" questions to clarify )

Comment: You mean `HttpClient`? Or are you trying to use a razor page to generate html for an email or something?

Comment: Given the nature of what can be done with Javascript, I don't see how anything less than a full browser could provide the final rendered web page source code.